Need help to find a simpler solution to a trivial question.
So here is the question


One of the roots of equation $2000x^6 + 100x^5 + 10x^3 + x - 2 = 0$ is of the form $(m+\sqrt n)/r$ where $m$ is a non-zero integer, and $r$ and $n$  are relatively prime natural numbers, then the value of $m + n + r$ is what?

The solution I have got:

Taking 2 common from the 2000x^6 and -2 and transposing them to the other side of the equation, we get 

$-2(1000x^6 - 1) = 100x^5 + 10x^3 + x $

As we can see the RHS is in G.P. Hence, I used the sum of the G.P. formula to get this

$ -2(1000x^6 + 1) = x(1000x^6 + 1)/10x^2 - 1$

From this, we get a quadratic, and upon solving it, we get the required root in the required form.
The root is

$(-1±√161)/40$

And the YAY, we got the answer, m + n + r = 200

Now, I am pretty sure there is a method that requires no use of taking the sum of G.P. because let us be honest, this method is just not it for this question, a question that requires applying the knowledge of the theory of equations.
Can someone help?

PS: The answers in Solve $2000x^6+100x^5+10x^3+x-2=0$ is not what I am looking for. Also, I know we get the answer with the methods given, but I believe there to be a simpler method, so please don't say "But you did get the answer with this method? Why look for other ones???"
I simply want to.
PS: I just got it! Check for the answer down below and see how simple the question was!

"As we can see the RHS is in G.P" No, it isn't.  It would be if it were $100x^{\color{blue}3} + 10x^2 + x$ but as it is $100x^{\color{red}5} + 0x^4 + 0x^3 + 10x^2 + x$ it is not.

my bad, it should be 10x^3. Thanks for pointing it out

The other approaches of 1/ "hope to factor out a quadratic of $Ax^2 + Bx \pm 1 \text{ or } 2 $" and 2/ Change of variables to $ w = 10x - 1/x$ are both sensible options and were listed in the link , but you indicated that's not what you want. Perhaps you can give an indication of what other methods you're thinking of? EG How else would you attempt to solve a septic?

This is a duplicate of Solve $2000x^6+100x^5+10x^3+x-2=0$ - your not liking the multiple methods used in the answers there doesn't really make this unique.  You could raise your concerns there if needed.

COMMENT.- Your equation can be put as $(20x^2+x-2)(100x^4+10x^2+1)=0$ then, because the biquadratic factor has discriminant negative, the root
$\dfrac{m+\sqrt n}{r}$ and its conjugate $\dfrac{m-\sqrt n}{r}$ should be both roots of the first quadratic factor. It follows easily that we have the values $\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{161}}{40}$. However I don't feel it is a simpler method than you have used.


$2000x^6 + 100x^5 + 10x^3 + x - 2 = 0$ 
$2(1000x^6 - 1) + x(100x^4 + 10x^2 + 1) = 0$

Apply $a^3 - b^3$ = ($a-b$)($a^2 + ab + b^2$) and take $(100x^4 + 10x^2 + 1)$ common.

$(100x^4 + 10x^2 + 1)(20x^2 - 2 + x) = 0$

Now clearly $(100x^4 + 10x^2 + 1)$ isn't equal to 0, at least when x is real. Hence, the roots of $(20x^2 - 2 + x)$ is the required root. And yes, we get the answer perfectly.
Using the quadratic formula, the roots of $(20x^2 - 2 + x)$ are

$(-1+\sqrt 161)/40$ = $(m+\sqrt n)/r$


Therefore, m + n + r = 200.

PS: This is what I meant by a simple answer, no GP, no nothing, just plain application of quadratic equations.
